# Google Play Games Services Multiplayer and Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-games

I am thinking about using Play Game Services, with turn-based multiplayer, to power my Android game.

I need to save the outcome of any game to my backend (here, Google App Engine) : mainly the winner and the score, for accounting purposes. However, I don't find any mention of a custom server in Play Games docs.

How can I combine GPGS multiplayer with a backend ? More specifically, how can I check if said user is effectively logged in to GPGS ?

Maybe the clients can send this data to the server, but I fear the data can be tampered with. And because it's a 1v1 battle, there is no way to check with other users if the data is correct.

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a multiplayer game using GPGS and I used the service 'Cloud Save' (now it has been changed to [Google Play Games Saved Games service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames)) to store the scores of each player. It is saved for each account, so the data can be loaded/saved from different devices.

Comment: What about save data security ? Is it hard enough to alter data ?